# ESLintとPrettierの設定ファイルを複数のプロジェクトから共通設定として参照したい

Tags: javascript, prettier, eslint

ローカルで複数のプロジェクトを開発する場合、一つ一つのプロジェクトでESLintとPrettierの設定ファイルを作るのではなく、共通の設定ファイルを参照するようにしたいです。
また、チーム開発しているプロジェクトではそのプロジェクトの設定ファイルがあるのでそれを使うようにしたいです。

いい方法はあるでしょうか？JetBrains社のエディタ（WebStormなど）での開発を想定しています。

Answer (score 0):

ESLint、Prettier 共に設定共有のための仕組みがあります。

- ESLint: Shareable Config https://eslint.org/docs/latest/extend/shareable-configs
- Prettier: Sharing configurations https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html

どちらの場合も module として公開し、各プロジェクトで参照するようにする方式です。